# Firestore Security Rules - Do not allow access to document which have more than one match in the rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following Firestore rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users {
      match /{userId} {
        allow get: if true;
        allow list: if isQueryLimitRespected(20);
        allow write: if false;
      }

      match /--stats-- {
        allow read, write: if false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements),

> It's possible for a document to match more than one match statement. In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the conditions is `true`.

How can I deny access to `--stats--`? Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

As I am not doing

```js
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users {
      match /{document=**} { <-------
        allow get: if true;
        allow list: if isQueryLimitRespected(20);
        allow write: if false;
      }

      match /--stats-- {
        allow read, write: if false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can re-organize my data structure in my database to:

```
/users (col)
   /--private-- (doc)
      /privateData (col)
         /stats (doc)

   /userId1 (doc)
   /userId2 (doc)
```

And secure this subcollection as follows:

```
    match /users {
      match /{userId} {
        allow get: if true;
        allow list: if isQueryLimitRespected(20);
        allow write: if false;
      }

      match /--private--/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if false;
      }
    }
```